# Why would a stock price have frequent very short, very high spikes?

Tags: equities

If I look at the five year price for GML on Yahoo Finance:
https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/gml/

I see many strange spikes:

[image: GML]
What could cause such behavior?

Comment: Very likely to be bad data...

Comment: Data from another source (barchart.com) shows that GML began 2016 in the 30's and the price rose smoothly to the high 40's at the end of 2016. No spikes .As you probably know GML ceased trading on 07/24/17.

Comment: it can also be ill-liquidity. If the price is calculated as (bestBid+bestAsk)/2, then if the ask is out of whack, that would make the mid price insane. Such out of whack ask prices can be due to illiquidity. So, there might not be nothing wrong with the data per-se, its just how the price is calculated

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is missing data. I've got a look on YAHOO Finance, the price was set to ZERO when no data is available. That's why you are seeing spikes on the graph.